# Ever heard of a Windows service called 'darkness'?

Tags: windows, virus, malware, services

Is it a malware? The computer has been diagnosed with some viruses.
I've tried looking [here](http://service.iamnotageek.com/) but haven't found any information about it yet.

Comment: Who marked this -1?  Its a genuine question.

Comment: Yah, I would agree. This question is legit and relevant information.

Comment: Maybe they wanted more detail, like a process name or error message.

Comment: What error message would there be? And the name of the service in question is clearly stated in the title?

Answer (score 2):

[3am Darkness](http://www.ca.com/us/securityadvisor/pest/pest.aspx?id=453073365)? Also, there is [a trojan](http://www.spynomore.com/trojan-darkness.htm) that shares the name.

Comment: The question is if these have a windows service called by that name. Why would a virus call its windows service by such an eye-attracting name?